# What's the problem with jquery burger menu?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i want this code to open and close `.sidebar` by toggling , it works in desktop chrome browser ( any screen size ) but it will not open `.sidebar` when `burger-menu` toggled.

```js
const toggleables = document.querySelectorAll('.toggleable')

const toggleIcon = (e) => {
  console.log(e.path);
  const icon = e.path.find((el) =>  el.classList.contains('toggleable'));

  if (icon.classList.contains('toggled')) {
    icon.classList.remove('toggled');
        $(".sidebar").hide();
  } else {
    icon.classList.add('toggled');
    $(".sidebar").show();
    }

};

toggleables.forEach((toggleable) => {
  toggleable.addEventListener('click', toggleIcon);
});
```

```css
.burger-menu {
  position: relative;
} .burger-menu .line-1 { top: 18px; }
  .burger-menu .line-2 { top: 32px; }
  .burger-menu .line {
    position: absolute;
    left: 27px;
    width: 22px;
    height: 1px;
    border-radius: 0;
    background-color: red;
    -webkit-transition: 0.2s;
    transition: 0.2s;
    opacity: 1;
} .burger-menu.toggled .line-3 { opacity: 0; }
  .burger-menu.toggled .line-1 {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(5px) rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform: translateY(5px) rotate(45deg);
    -o-transform: translateY(5px) rotate(45deg);
    transform: translateY(5px) rotate(45deg);
} .burger-menu.toggled .line-2 {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-8px) rotate(-45deg);
    -moz-transform: translateY(-8px) rotate(-45deg);
    -o-transform: translateY(-8px) rotate(-45deg);
    transform: translateY(-8px) rotate(-45deg);
}
.sidebar {
display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <div class="menu" title="menu">
  <div class="burger-menu toggleable ">
    <span class="line line-1"></span>
    <span class="line line-2"></span>
    </div>
  </div>


 <div class="sidebar">
  <ul style="list-style:none;">
  <li>Opened</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Jquery version 3 handle just the modern browser, use version 1.x.x because it handle even internet explorer version.

Comment: @PascalTovohery — **Danger** jQuery 1.x is no longer supported and has known security problems. **Do not use it**

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on Stack Overflow, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) for Stack Overflow to distribute that content. By Stack Overflow policy, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post, please take a look at [How does deleting work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5222)

Comment: The code you use has no bearing on your choice of CDN. The only variations between CDNs are how quickly they load for different people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<div class="burger-menu toggleable ">` has `height: auto` (the default) and no content in normal flow (all its children are absolutely positioned).

This makes its computed height `0`, which gives zero pixels that you can click on to trigger the click event.

Give it a height.

Also, replace it with a `<button>` element (which will be in the tab order and announced as a clickable element by screen readers).

Comment: its true , ```menu ``` class needs height , Thanks <3